# Button:pointerover flicker after upgrade to latest Avalonia version (11.0.4)

Tags: button, flicker, mousehover, avalonia

I've got the following button Style selector in my app.axaml:

```
<Style Selector="Button.RoundedButton" >
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5"/>
  <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Panel>
          <Image Source="\Resources\Bitmaps\Buttons\BtnRoundedNormal.png" Classes="SetupButtonImage"/>
          <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"></TextBlock>
        </Panel>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<Style Selector="Button.RoundedButton:pointerover" >
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Panel>

          <Image Source="\Resources\Bitmaps\Buttons\BtnRoundedHover.png" Classes="SetupButtonImage"/>
          <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"></TextBlock>
        </Panel>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
<Style Selector="Button.RoundedButton:pressed" >
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Panel>
          <Image Source="\Resources\Bitmaps\Buttons\BtnRoundedPushed.png" Classes="SetupButtonImage"/>
          <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Orange" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"></TextBlock>
        </Panel>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

and then I create a button from this template in my MainWindow.axaml:

```
  <Button  DockPanel.Dock="Left"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Classes="RoundedButton" x:Name="MyButton"     Width="100" Content="Current +"       Click="MyButtonClicked"/>
```

This used to work well until I upgraded today to the latest avalonia version (11.0.4) and now the button flickers when the mouse is hovering over it. The button is also not very responsive, I have to press it for quite a while until it calls the click event handler.

Any ideas what caused this and how to fix it?

I tried with different Themes (FluentTheme and SimpleTheme), still flickers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the template in the event based pseudoclass selectors (such as pointerover).  Set the template in the main style and and change properties of the underlying template controls with another selector.

For example:

```xml
<Style Selector="Button.RoundedButton:pressed /template/ TextBlock">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange"/>
</Style>
```

Don't be afraid to use multiple styles and selectors with the same pseudoclass to target the TextBlock separately from the Image.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In your code, how can I have a Setter that sets the Image to make an image button. It does not seem to work with TextBlock. Do I need a different template?

Comment: As you can see here: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Controls/Image.cs 

Image's SourceProperty is a StyledProperty, so it will behave in the same manner as I demonstrated with TextBlock Foreground.  You just have to select the image and set the Source through a setter in the same way.

Comment: I tried this, it compiles and runs, however the button do not show the image, they are just normal buttons:

<Style Selector="Button.RoundedButton /template/ Image">
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="BtnRoundedNormal.png"/>
 </Style>